# Qual a melhor maneira de passar um context para uma classe aninhada?

Tags: android, android-context

Tenho uma classe aninhada que é usada para uma nova `Thread` e nela possui alguns `Toast` para apresentar algumas informaçoes pro usuário dependendo do erro. 

Já tentei passar o context pelo Construtor, já criei uma variavel context na classe principal porém o erro persiste com a mensagem:

> br.com.minhaempresa.teste.AccountAccessActivity$LoginRunnable.run(AccountAccessActivity.java:97)

Código:

```
public class AccountAccessActivity extends Activity implements AccountAccess
{
private EditText account;
private EditText pass;
private Spinner spinner;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_access);

    account = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.accountInput);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passInput);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.accTypeSpinner);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressCircle);

    context = this;

    if(!InternetConnectionStatus.isOnline(context))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context ,R.string.noInternet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void login(View v)
{
    LoginForm form = new LoginForm(account.getText(), pass.getText(), spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

    Runnable runnable = new LoginRunnable(form, this);

    new Thread(runnable).start();
}

@Override
public void forgotPassword(View v)
{

}

@Override
public void newAccount(View v)
{

}

public class LoginRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private LoginForm form;

    public LoginRunnable(LoginForm form, Context context)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(new ConnectionFactory().getConnection());

            userDAO.validadeLogin(form);
        }
        catch (SQLTimeoutException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.timeLimitExceded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.erroUserOrPass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.internalErro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Linha 97:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3642
>                                                                                    Process: br.com.minhaempresa.db, PID: 7007
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:372)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:105)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:313)
>                                                                                        at br.com.minhaempresa.somdegustacao.AccountAccessActivity$LoginRunnable.run(AccountAccessActivity.java:98)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Qual a melhor maneira  de passar o Context para uma classe aninhada neste caso?

Comment: Você omitiu do log de erros a parte principal: a exceção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não tem a ver com a forma como o *context* é passado.

A razão do erro é que não é permitido aceder a objectos que usam a *UI*, como é o caso de *Toast*, em uma *Thread* que não a *UIThread(MainThread)*.
Se retirar as chamadas a *Toast* verá que o erro desaparece.

Existem várias formas de resolver esse problema, uma delas é executar o *Toast* usando o método `runOnUiThread()` da *Activity*:

```
public static class LoginRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private LoginForm form;
    private WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;

    public LoginRunnable(LoginForm form, Activity activity)
    {
        this.form = form;
        weakActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(new ConnectionFactory().getConnection());

            userDAO.validadeLogin(form);
        }
        catch (SQLTimeoutException e)
        {
            showError(R.string.timeLimitExceded);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            showError(R.string.erroUserOrPass);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            showError(R.string.internalErro);
        }
    }

    private void showError(final int messageId){
        final Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if(activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String message = activity.getString(messageId);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Declarar a classe *LoginRunnable* `static` e usar uma [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) para guardar a referência à *Activity* evita quaisquer possíveis *memory leaks*.

Comment: Finalmente entendi o uso do 'runOnUIThread'! Percebi que o erro não era o context depois de dar uma olhada melhor na exceção, obrigado!

Comment: Só que a runOnUIThread roda direto na Thread principal, a do Usuário, e como o ramaral comentou, se não considerar possíveis memory leaks, use.

Comment: @CarlosBridi Note que a sua solução também tem problemas de possíveis *memory leaks* já que passa a Activity para o runnable.

Comment: @ramaral Concordo, só complementei que ela roda na thread principal. obrigado

Comment: @CarlosBridi O que roda na Thread principal é só o Toast. Essa não é a razão de provocar possíveis *memory leaks*. A razão é por a classe não ser declarada como `static`, tendo assim uma referência à Activity.

Comment: @CarlosBridi Editei a resposta de forma a evitar *memory leaks*

Comment: @ramaral Show, obrigado pelos ensinamentos!

Comment: @ramaral não entendi mt bem esse trecho 'if(activity != null)', pelo que entendi 'weakActivity.get()' pode me retornar um null, então qual a garantia de que meu Toast ira aparecer? Se puder me dar uma explicação básica sobre WeakReference ficaria grato, ou se preferir abro um tópico a respeito disso.

Comment: Você já deve saber que o Android pode destruir e recriar a sua Activity em certas situações, por exemplo quando o dispositivo é rodado da posição vertical para a horizontal e vice-versa. Se a classe *LoginRunnable* tiver uma "referência forte" à Activity ela não pode ser destruída. Quando o Android recriar a Activity ficarão duas Activities em memória. Se a referência à Activity, guardada por *LoginRunnable* for fraca(*WeakReference*), permitirá que a memória ocupada pela Activity antiga seja libertada quando o Android criar uma nova.

Answer (score 0):

Também já tive problemas com contextos em classes diferentes, e é meio ~trabalhoso~ controlar isso. O que você pode fazer é criar uma interface Listener com um método que retorne exceção para a classe que invocou.

Exemplo:

Interface:

```
public interface DoLoginListener{
    public void onException(String erroMsg) throws Exception;
}
```

Classe principal:

```
public class AccountAccessActivity extends Activity implements AccountAccess, DoLoginListener{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

...

}


public void onException(String erroMsg) throws Exception{
   Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), erroMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

Classe Login:

public class LoginRunnable implements Runnable{
    private LoginForm form;
    private DoLoginListener callback;

```
public LoginRunnable(LoginForm form, DoLoginListener<String> cba)
{
    this.form = form;
    this.callback = cba;
}


@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO(new ConnectionFactory().getConnection());

        userDAO.validadeLogin(form);
    }
    catch (SQLTimeoutException e){
        callback.onException("Erro de SQLTimeOut");
        //ou podes passar o R.string.<teuErro> 
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        callback.onException("Erro de SQLException");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        callback.onException("Erro de ClassNotFoundException ");
    }
}
```

}

Assim você sabe qual classe instanciou e pode exibir pro usuário de formas diferentes.